# How can I access my Assets from my View class?

Tags: java, android, fonts, assets, typeface

I am trying to import custom loaded fonts using a Typeface. In order to do this I must access my Assets. When I run the following code through my MainActivity class which extends Activity, it does not throw an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/EuphoriaScript.otf"); 
}
```

When I run it through my View class, it throws an exception on the getAssets() method. I am guessing this is because it needs to be accessed in a different way. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: whats the issue i means any errors?

Comment: Are you sure you get an Exception ? Isn't it a compilation error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) is attached to your application package. So to get access to it you simply need a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Every view holds a reference to it's [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) so to get an AssetManger from a View class simply do :

```
AssetManager assetManger = getContext().getAssets();
```